# Commandline to set perms on SQL's backup folder

Tags: windows, security, ftp

I'm trying to get my webhost to grant me permissions to the daily backup folder used by sql server. I'd like to use FTP to access all files in that folder.

i'd like to give the host a nice easy commandline(s) to execute so they don't have an excuse to come back to me with any sort of security or complexity complaints.

So the commandlines should:

- create the user account (with
  password)
- explicitly disable all sorts of
  access except FTP
- set the FTP homepage (and
  permissions) of that account to
  nothing more the folder containing
  our db's backup

[And i'd like to not have to explain to you guys how it is that i come to have such a lame webhost that i have to provide them directions like this.]

thx

Comment: Well, I can't imagine why a webhost would do this... for some of the sites I host, I take backups, I look after them, I manage everything - I wouldn't give a client access to those backups. For my other clients who have managed hosting and their won installation of SQL that is different, but in which case, you should be able to do this yourself.... Can't you take a backup yourself using tools or a script and copy it to your FTP folder or similar.. If my host ran automation and stuff, I would be happy in their knowledge that they are managing it but I wouldn't put in a request like this.

Comment: But if the client _asked for daily backups...you'd provide that, right? This is actually a migration away from the existing host...we have no root access at either the db or http server. They are basically just being stinkers.